# Tableau - cannot mix aggregate and non aggreagte comparisons in IF statement

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to do something very simple, and getting this error.

```
IF [ORDER_LATE] = "Y" THEN [ORDER_QTY] END
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `[ORDER_LATE]` is your non aggregate and `[ORDER_QTY]` is your aggregate.

Create a separate calculated field called `[LateOrder]` for determining a boolean value for your `[ORDER_LATE]` dimension, this will be able to interact with your aggregated `[ORDER_QTY]`.

```
IF UPPER([ORDER_LATE]) = "Y" THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END
```

(Or equivalently, just `UPPER([ORDER_LATE]) = “Y”` since booleans are first class expressions)

Go back to your original calc and replace *`[ORDER_LATE] = "Y"`* with *`[LateOrder] = TRUE`*

```
IF [LateOrder] = TRUE THEN [ORDER_QTY] END
```

(Or equivalently, just `IF [LateOrder] THEN [ORDER_QTY] END` since the = TRUE is redundant)

However I do not know if you are calculating your order quantity at a fixed LOD, if so, the above solution may not be correct.

Check out this post on [how to fix Tableau aggregate and non-aggregate errors](https://community.tableau.com/s/news/a0A4T000002e5JoUAI/how-to-fix-tableau-error-cannot-mix-aggregate-and-non-aggregate-arguments). It does a good job explaining why this happens and a few different ways to go about fixing these types of errors.